# Python xml ElementTree from a string source?

Tags: python, xml

The ElementTree.parse reads from a file, how can I use this if I already have the XML data in a string?

Maybe I am missing something here, but there must be a way to use the ElementTree without writing out the string to a file and reading it again.

[xml.etree.elementtree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If you're using `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse` to parse from a file, then you can use `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring` to get the root `Element` of the document. Often you don't actually need an `ElementTree`.

See [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: The problem is that ElementTree.fromstring generates an element, and not an ElementTree! Anyone knows how to work around this?

Comment: Same problem as @SamuelLampa mentioned. I is not a ElementTree, I am not able to do `getroot()` for this

Comment: @SamuelLampa see [dgassaway's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18281386/12744), use `ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xmlstring))`

Comment: for the correct answer, see the one provided by @dgassaway

Comment: Don't forget the import statements

Comment: What's the string version of iterparse(), i.e., fromstring's iterative version?

Comment: @SiddharthMenon you don't need getroot() `fromstring` gives you the root already.

Comment: I corrected this answer by adding that `ElementTree.fromstring()` returns the root `Element` not an `ElementTree`.

Answer (score 343):

You can parse the text as a string, which creates an Element, and create an ElementTree using that Element.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xmlstring))
```

I just came across this issue and the documentation, while complete, is not very straightforward on the difference in usage between the [`parse()`](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) and [`fromstring()`](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) methods.

Comment: The second line can be simply `root = ET.fromstring(xmlstring)`. Equals `ET.parse('file.xml').getroot()`: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml

Comment: @Anton, as the OP states, the idea is to generate an ElementTree, and not an Element. This is useful, for instance, when you want to use ElementTree.write().

Comment: If anyone is curious this also works for `lxml`

Answer (score 20):

You need the `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(text)`

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring
myxml = fromstring(text)
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not an `ElementTree` it is the root `Element`. This API is different and can't do all the same things.

Answer (score 12):

[io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.StringIO) is another option for getting XML into [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```py
import io
f = io.StringIO(xmlstring)
tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()
```

Hovever, it does not affect the XML declaration one would assume to be in `tree` (although that's needed for [ElementTree.write()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write)). See [How to write XML declaration using xml.etree.ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356641/how-to-write-xml-declaration-using-xml-etree-elementtree).