# Parsing xml in Python using a custom element class

Tags: python, xml

I'd like to parse an xml document using Python's xml.etree.ElementTree module. However, I want all the elements in the resulting tree object to have some class methods that I define. This suggests creating my own subclass of Python's element class, but I'm having trouble telling the parser to use my own element subclass when parsing, instead of the built in class.

For example, let's say I want the nodes in the tree to have a new method called custommethod(). To do this, I create an element subclass:

```
class MyElement(xml.etree.ElementTree._Element):

    def custommethod():
        . . .
```

Now, when I parse a tree using

```
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(source)
```

I want all the elements in tree to have the custommethod() method. So,

```
tree.getroot.custommethod()
```

should not fail.

But I don't know how to tell the parser to use my element class - is this even possible? There are some hints in the Python documentation about passing a custom parser to .parse(), but not a lot of details.

Answer (score 3):

A custom XML parser is a subclass of `xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser` with four functions defined:

1. `start(self, tag, attrs)` Called when an opening tag is found.
2. `end(self, tag)` Called when an closing tag is found.
3. `data(self, data)` Called when data is found.
4. `close(self)` Called at the end of the parse.

You must manage everything else, how the node's instances are created, the depth of each tag, etc.
Notice that the `data(self, data)` method doesn't have a tag argument.

Comment: How does one go about doing the "manage everything else" part? I haven't been able to find any documentation on that, either here on SO or in the Python documentation, nor with pretty extensive googling. I don't expect a whole tutorial or anything, but a few hints, or a link to a document or something...?

Answer (score 1):

The book Dive Into Python has quite an extensive coverage of this subject. This chapter is online. Near the bottom are the [steps explained to create a custom XML parser](http://www.diveintopython.net/xml_processing/parsing_xml.html). Not sure if it gets you the information you need, but perhaps it's a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I wasn't aware that this book was available for free.

Comment: That link seems to be dead.

Comment: @gerrit, thanks, I updated the link, guess it was moved. Note that the whole book is available freely and there are more chapters on XML.

Answer (score 1):

In `Python3`, monkey patching of the Element class did not work properly. I suspect it is due to three reasons:

1. Overriding `__class__` / `__dict` etc of the built-in class doesn't work.
2. `ElementTree` uses `C` to do heavy lifting.
3. The classes used to parse is a web of class instantiations.

**Solution:** Create your own parse function!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
def parse(source):
    """Parse wrapper to build a tree with the extended Node class"""
    treebuilder = xml.etree.ElementTree.TreeBuilder(element_factory=MyElement)
    parser = xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser(target=treebuilder)
    tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(source, parser)
    return tree
```

The example above uses your **`MyElement`** class instead of `ElementTree.Element` for every object of the tree.

Comment: Awesome! To parse element from string, in addition check @dgassaway [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18281386/10815899)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a custom method to `_Element`

```
>>> def customMethod(self):
    print("Done!")

>>> e._Element.customMethod=customMethod
```

Comment: This almost worked. One of the things I want to do is change the tag of the element, which means doing self.tag = "something else" in the function. If I do this, I can call the function as a method of _Element, but it only prints("Done!") without changing the tag.

Comment: Assigning a new custom method after parsing the tree got me looking, and I found this, which is almost the right thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962962/python-changing-methods-and-attributes-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the element class to use while creating the `TreeBuilder` instance, like this:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree

class MyCustomElement(etree.Element):
    pass

tb = etree.TreeBuilder(element_factory=MyCustomElement)
```

Ref: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1370

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for this problem and found lxml supports it directly.

```py
>>> from lxml import etree

>>> class honk(etree.ElementBase):
...    @property
...    def honking(self):
...       return self.get('honking') == 'true'
```

look at [lxml](https://lxml.de/element_classes.html) element classes