# How to write XML declaration using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am generating an XML document in Python using an [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), but the `tostring` function doesn't include an [XML declaration](http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml) when converting to plaintext.

```python
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, tostring

document = Element('outer')
node = SubElement(document, 'inner')
node.NewValue = 1
print tostring(document)  # Outputs "<outer><inner /></outer>"
```

I need my string to include the following XML declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
```

However, there does not seem to be any documented way of doing this.

Is there a proper method for rendering the XML declaration in an `ElementTree`?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I am surprised to find that there doesn't seem to be a way with `ElementTree.tostring()`. You can however use `ElementTree.ElementTree.write()` to write your XML document to a fake file:

```
from io import BytesIO
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

document = ET.Element('outer')
node = ET.SubElement(document, 'inner')
et = ET.ElementTree(document)

f = BytesIO()
et.write(f, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True) 
print(f.getvalue())  # your XML file, encoded as UTF-8
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997848/emitting-namespace-specifications-with-elementtree-in-python). Even then, I don't think you can get your 'standalone' attribute without writing prepending it yourself.

Comment: why do you define the "node" variable here?

Comment: Thanks this line et.write(f, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True) saved my day

Comment: is there a pretty print parameter for ´et.write()´? or any other way to generate a xml with line-breaks?

Comment: @jan-seins Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python

Comment: Be aware that this function is not available in versions < 3.9

Answer (score 32):

I would use lxml (see http://lxml.de/api.html).

Then you can:

```
from lxml import etree
document = etree.Element('outer')
node = etree.SubElement(document, 'inner')
print(etree.tostring(document, xml_declaration=True))
```

Answer (score 25):

[If you include the `encoding='utf8'`, you will get an XML header](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1470809):

> xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring writes a XML encoding declaration with encoding='utf8'

Sample Python code (works with Python 2 and 3):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(
    ElementTree.fromstring('<xml><test>123</test></xml>')
)
root = tree.getroot()

print('without:')
print(ElementTree.tostring(root, method='xml'))
print('')
print('with:')
print(ElementTree.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml'))
```

Python 2 output:

```
$ python2 example.py
without:
<xml><test>123</test></xml>

with:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<xml><test>123</test></xml>
```

With Python 3 you will note [the `b` prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) indicating byte literals are returned (just like with Python 2):

```
$ python3 example.py
without:
b'<xml><test>123</test></xml>'

with:
b"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>\n<xml><test>123</test></xml>"
```

Comment: In Python 3, escape characters will be shown in the declaration when printing. `<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf8\'?>`

Comment: What helped in this answer is wondering why you were doing so much of this `Elementree.Elementree(Elementree.fromstring(...` and I now realize `fromstring` returns an `element` not an `ElementTree`, whereas the `parse` method does return an `ElementTree`. This make trying to mock an xml file in a test suite by using a string very confusing! If you take that element and run `tostring`, it allows those encoding & method parameters, but the output is missing the `<?xml` declaration line, and now I see that is because it is not the full document.

Comment: Note that `utf8` is NOT a valid character encoding string. That's also why Python3 adds the declaration and returns the whole thing as Bytes instead of string.

Comment: @mbirth so the method should be stated as "tobytes" not 'tostring'.

Comment: @MarekMarczak No, the XML should read `encoding='utf-8'` to be valid.

Comment: You mean the declaration or actual text encoding? The result is 'bytes', not 'string'. It's just confusing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works exactly as needed.

Answer (score 21):

### xml_declaration Argument

> Is there a proper method for rendering the XML declaration in an ElementTree?

YES, and there is no need of using `.tostring` function. According to [ElementTree Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree), you should **create an ElementTree object**, create Element and SubElements, **set the tree's root**, and finally use `xml_declaration` argument in `.write` function, so the declaration line is included in output file.

You can do it this way:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.ElementTree("tree")

document = ET.Element("outer")
node1 = ET.SubElement(document, "inner")
node1.text = "text"

tree._setroot(document)
tree.write("./output.xml", encoding = "UTF-8", xml_declaration = True)
```

And the output file is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<outer><inner>text</inner></outer>
```

Comment: This works for me and seems to be the most "correct" solution

Answer (score 4):

I encounter this issue recently, after some digging of the code, I found the following code snippet is definition of function `ElementTree.write`

```
def write(self, file, encoding="us-ascii"):
    assert self._root is not None
    if not hasattr(file, "write"):
        file = open(file, "wb")
    if not encoding:
        encoding = "us-ascii"
    elif encoding != "utf-8" and encoding != "us-ascii":
        file.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='%s'?>\n" % 
     encoding)
    self._write(file, self._root, encoding, {})
```

So the answer is, if you need write the XML header to your file, set the `encoding` argument other than `utf-8` or `us-ascii`, e.g. `UTF-8`

Comment: It would be a nice albeit brittle hack, but it doesn't seem to work (the encoding is probably lower-cased before that). Also, `ElementTree.ElementTree.write()` is documented to have a `xml_declaration` paramater (see the accepted answer). But `ElementTree.tostring()` doesn't have that parameter, which was the method asked in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

**Easy**

Sample for both Python 2 and 3 (**encoding** parameter must be **utf8**):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring('<xml><test>123</test></xml>'))
root = tree.getroot()
print(ElementTree.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml'))
```

From Python 3.8 there is **xml_declaration** parameter for that stuff:

> New in version 3.8: The xml_declaration and default_namespace
> parameters.

> xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(element, encoding="us-ascii",
> method="xml", *, xml_declaration=None, default_namespace=None,
> short_empty_elements=True) Generates a string representation of an XML
> element, including all subelements. element is an Element instance.
> encoding 1 is the output encoding (default is US-ASCII). Use
> encoding="unicode" to generate a Unicode string (otherwise, a
> bytestring is generated). method is either "xml", "html" or "text"
> (default is "xml"). xml_declaration, default_namespace and
> short_empty_elements has the same meaning as in ElementTree.write().
> Returns an (optionally) encoded string containing the XML data.

Sample for Python 3.8 and higher:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring('<xml><test>123</test></xml>'))
root = tree.getroot()
print(ElementTree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', method='xml', xml_declaration=True))
```

Comment: Of all these examples, this is the way! Results in XML with the `<?xml...` declaration, which has a valid encoding attribute: `utf-8`, not `utf8`.

Answer (score 2):

The minimal working example with `ElementTree` package usage:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

document = ET.Element('outer')
node = ET.SubElement(document, 'inner')
node.text = '1'
res = ET.tostring(document, encoding='utf8', method='xml').decode()
print(res)
```

the output is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<outer><inner>1</inner></outer>
```

Comment: Unfortunately utf8' isn't valid XML, but 'UTF-8' is https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#id6

Answer (score 1):

Another pretty simple option is to concatenate the desired header to the string of xml like this:

```
xml = (bytes('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n', encoding='utf-8') + ET.tostring(root))
xml = xml.decode('utf-8')
with open('invoice.xml', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(xml)
```

Comment: It gives this error : TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ET](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
try:
    from lxml import etree
    print("running with lxml.etree")
except ImportError:
    try:
        # Python 2.5
        import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
        print("running with cElementTree on Python 2.5+")
    except ImportError:
        try:
            # Python 2.5
            import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
            print("running with ElementTree on Python 2.5+")
        except ImportError:
            try:
                # normal cElementTree install
                import cElementTree as etree
                print("running with cElementTree")
            except ImportError:
               try:
                   # normal ElementTree install
                   import elementtree.ElementTree as etree
                   print("running with ElementTree")
               except ImportError:
                   print("Failed to import ElementTree from any known place")

document = etree.Element('outer')
node = etree.SubElement(document, 'inner')
print(etree.tostring(document, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if you just want to print. Getting an error when I try to send it to a file...

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

def prettify(elem):
    rough_string = ET.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Including 'standalone' in the declaration

I didn't found any alternative for adding the `standalone` argument in the documentation so I adapted the `ET.tosting` function to take it as an argument.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

# Sample
document = ET.Element('outer')
node = ET.SubElement(document, 'inner')
et = ET.ElementTree(document)

 # Function that you need   
 def tostring(element, declaration, encoding=None, method=None,):
     class dummy:
         pass
     data = []
     data.append(declaration+"\n")
     file = dummy()
     file.write = data.append
     ET.ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding, method=method)
     return "".join(data)
# Working example
xdec = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>"""    
xml = tostring(document, encoding='utf-8', declaration=xdec)
```